# Is it possible to use variables in markdown doxygen

Tags: markdown, doxygen

So basicly i want to use variables in my documentation in doxygen and i wonder if it's possible.

For example i want to do something like:
my_variable = variable_value
and in other pages just use my_variable to display variable_value.

I know it's possible to do this by adding to doxyfile config
`ALIASES += "my_variable=variable_value"`
and then to show it
`@ref my_variable`
But is it possible to do something like that without making changes in config?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?  Where should the required information from? Maybe `#my_variable`  or a "normal" markdown link would work.

Comment: doxygen 1.9.1
it's just in markdown document, I'm not using these variables in code or anything like that, I just want to add the required setup version to documentation.
I have already tried 
#def my_variable variable_value and then /ref variable_value,
#define my_variable variable_value and then /ref variable_value,
[my_variable]: "variable_value" and then [my_variable],
and none of this worked, also tried your suggestion with #my_variable and same result

Comment: Doxygen 1.9.1 is a bit older the current version is 1.10.0 What do you mean with "setup version"? Where do you get the value from? Maybe you can use an environment variable like `$(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)` Please give an example.

Comment: I mean for example using aliases in config file: ALIASES += "XCode=15.1" and then somewhere in the documentation "Requirements XCode @ref XCode" to display the version. But instead of declaring this variable in config file can i declare it anywhere else and if possible how can i achieve this

Comment: You could define an environment variable `XCode` with the value `15.1` (like in Windows `set XCODE=15.1` or *nix `export XCODE=15.1` and use in your markdownfile `$(XCODE)` and doxygen will pickup this value.

Comment: Do you know if i can define it in markdown file or it's impossible?

Comment: What did you try so far? what do you mean with "Do you know if i can define it in markdown file or it's impossible?" ? The usage (`$(...)`) can be in the markdown file for doxygen (I don't know about other markdown processors) and the setting like `export XCODE=15.1` is outside the markdown file.